# How do I switch on the backlight on the WASD Code Keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-navigation

I just got a http://codekeyboards.com/ keyboard but can't work out how to switch the backlighting on. Ideas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The user's guide for the WASD v2 keyboards (including the CODE) can be found [here](https://support.wasdkeyboards.com/hc/en-us/articles/115009171708-Keyboard-Manuals).

You will note that Fn + F11 and Fn + F12 are used to adjust the backlight, but will only function if DIP switch #6 is set to the ON position on the bottom of your keyboard.

<sup>Source: This answer was typed on a CODE keyboard. :-)</sup>

Comment: And note that there are tiny icons on the front edge of the keys (not that anyone would ever see these until after they have come looking for how to turn on the backlight ;-)

Comment: Don't forget to unplug and plug it back in if not already after moving the dip switch

Answer (score 3):

Function + F12 toggles backlighting on/off. Function + F11 should cycle between the backlighting levels, from lowest to brightest.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the [61-key CODE keyboard](http://www.wasdkeyboards.com/index.php/products/code-keyboard/code-61-key-mechanical-keyboard-mx-green.html), use `Fn`+`X` to cycle the LED mode between

- off (default)
- on
- recently touched
- on, but snore when it hasn't been touched in a while

`Fn`+`C` turns down the brightness, and `Fn`+`V` turns up the brightness.